# Laravel Backpack file upload

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I recently installed laravel backpack
And my form has a pdf file to upload
I read the tutorial on backpack but was unable to solve it

I Debugged and found that
request()->hasFile() is empty
no file in request
and html code of the add form has no enctype="" in it

Comment: how are you showing the file input, refer [this](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#upload-1) in docs.

Comment: can you post your Model and Controller [field code] code

Answer (score 0):

**routes/web.php**

```
<?php
  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
  
use App\Http\Controllers\FileUploadController;
  
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
  
Route::get('file-upload', [FileUploadController::class, 'fileUpload'])->name('file.upload');
Route::post('file-upload', [FileUploadController::class, 'fileUploadPost'])->name('file.upload.post');
```

**Create FileUploadController**
**app/Http/Controllers/FileUploadController.php**

```
<?php
   
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  
class FileUploadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function fileUpload()
    {
        return view('fileUpload');
    }
  
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function fileUploadPost(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf,xlx,csv|max:2048',
        ]);
  
    $fileName = time().'.'.$request->file->extension();  

    $request->file->move(public_path('uploads'), $fileName);

    return back()
        ->with('success','You have successfully upload file.')
        ->with('file',$fileName);

}
```

}

**Create Blade File**

**resources/views/fileUpload.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>laravel 8 file upload example - ItSolutionStuff.com.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
  
<body>
<div class="container">
   
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading"><h2>laravel 8 file upload example - ItSolutionStuff.com.com</h2></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
   
        @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </div>
        @endif
  
        @if (count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
  
        <form action="{{ route('file.upload.post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="row">
  
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control">
                </div>
   
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
                </div>
   
            </div>
        </form>
  
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Backpack is for admin CRUD functionalities. All you need to do in the admin controller is to define the field type as "Browse" for file upload. Example, below is to upload and file. It will upload single file in your laravel default filesystem and save the path in photo_path field of database.

```
     $this->crud->addField([ // Photo
        'name' => 'photo_path',
        'label' => "Photo",
        'type' => 'browse'], 'both');
```

This is for the admin only, if you want upload feature for frontend, Backpack API's are not for that. In that case, check in Laravel docs.